# Azure mobile service log in credentials

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I created an Azure mobile service and published the sample project that the website provides. When I try to visit the service from browser using my service URL (an example is https://test.azure-mobile.net/help), service is asking me for credentials. I tried using the Azure credentials but they don't work.

What credentials is it asking?\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the application key or the master key from your mobile service. In the Azure portal, go to your mobile service and in the dashboard select the *manage keys* option on the bottom of the page. You should use this key as the password, and any value (even empty) for the user name.

[image]

Comment: That worked. Thanks! But I'm unable to see my request in Fiddler as the service is using a pop up window to make the request. How can I do that? I need to look more into how authentication works with this service. I tried copying what I have in the browser address bar into Fiddler but authorization was denied.

Comment: If using Fiddler, you can set the `x-zumo-application` header with your application key. For example, send a `GET your-service/tables/todoitem` request with the `x-zumo-application: <your app key>` via Fiddler and it should work.